# Does 'turn around' mean 180° or 360°?

Tags: word-meaning, phrasal-verbs

> 2. So as to rotate and face in the opposite direction.

So it's what Lexico says on the meaning of the adverb 'around'. And yet, if we talk about, say, a woman showing her new dress, she would probably turn 360 degrees when asked to turn around by her boyfriend. So what does 'turn around' mean when both 180° and 360° are possible based on the context?

Comment: Arguably, the point of turning is to show her backside, which happens when she's turned 180°. The only other time I can think of where "turn around" doesn't mean 180° is when you turn "around and around," which means turning 360° at least twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

99 out of 100 people will turn 180 degrees.
[Turn around vs Turn back](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/47501/turn-around-vs-turn-back)

Comment: From a management announcement: “Last year our company faced in the wrong direction. Now we’ve turned by 360 degrees.”